# HDFS - Namenode not starting

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Has anyone encountered this before. I am trying to restart the namenode through Ambari dashboard.

```
2016-11-27 19:24:09,588 ERROR namenode.NameNode (NameNode.java:main(1712)) - Failed to start namenode.
    java.io.IOException: Multiple shared edits directories are not yet supported
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNamespaceEditsDirs(FSNamesystem.java:1429)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNamespaceEditsDirs(FSNamesystem.java:1414)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkConfiguration(FSNamesystem.java:624)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:676)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:662)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:722)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:951)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:935)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1641)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1707)
```

Answer (score 1):

`java.io.IOException: Multiple shared edits directories are not yet supported` is thrown when `dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir` has multiple entries. Could you check thie configuration is correct?
`dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir` is not necessary unless you are trying to launch HA NameNode cluster.

If you are using QJM, [official documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html#Deployment) can be a help. We need to write set value like this.

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir</name>
  <value>qjournal://node1.example.com:8485;node2.example.com:8485;node3.example.com:8485/mycluster</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be more of a comment, but I don't have enough reputation for that.  To perhaps save the next person some time, in the `<value>` of the `dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir` config key, be sure that the `host:port` listing of the JournalNodes is separated by *semicolons*, *NOT COMMAS*.  Even after seeing the answer above, my eyes kept glossing over the delimiters and I spent way more time on this problem than I should have.